# How do you get all the value in an object using ramda

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

how do you map to all the object and get all the value using ramda

```
const input ={
  a: 'apple',
  b:{
    c:{
      d:{
        e: 'egg',
        f: 'fish'
      }
    },
    g: 'guava',
    h: 'honey',
  }
}
```

console.log :

```
['apple',
'egg',
'fish',
'guava',
'honey']
```

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#flatten-a-nested-object-into-dot-separated-key--value-pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()`, and `Array.flatMap()` to create a recursive function that gets the values from an object, and then iterates the values, and calls itself on every value that is an object:

```js
const getDeepValues = obj => Object
  .values(obj)
  .flatMap(v => typeof v === 'object' ? getDeepValues(v) : v)

const input = {"a":"apple","b":{"c":{"d":{"e":"egg","f":"fish"}},"g":"guava","h":"honey"}}

const result = getDeepValues(input)

console.log(result)
```

You can create a pointfree function with Ramda, that does the same thing:

1. Get the values,
2. Use R.When with `R.is(Object)` to check if the value is an object, and call `getDeepValues` on the value if it is (the arrow function is needed because the `getDeepValues` is not declared yet), or return the value if it's not.

```js
const { pipe, values, chain, when, is } = R

const getDeepValues = pipe(
  values, // get the values
  chain(when(is(Object), v => getDeepValues(v))) // if the value is an object use getDeepValues or just return the value
)

const input = {"a":"apple","b":{"c":{"d":{"e":"egg","f":"fish"}},"g":"guava","h":"honey"}}

const result = getDeepValues(input)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you then its possible to use Ramda to filter the value

Comment: This is very nice.  I would love to figure out a Ramda alternative that loses that last point `(v) => getDeepValues(v)`, but only to see it done.  I prefer the vanilla version here.

Comment: @B_B - your welcome. You can do it with Ramda, but the vanilla is easier a more readable.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - yep, the arrow function is annoying :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Ramda, you can do it in plan JS in one cleverly-written recursive [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const getDeepValues = obj => Object
  .values(obj) // 1. iterate over the object values
  .reduce((acc, cur) => [
    ...acc, // 3. pass previous values
    ...(
      cur instanceof Object // 4. if the value we encounter is an object...
      ? getDeepValues(cur)  // ...then use recursion to add all deep values
      : [cur]               // ...else add one string
    ),
  ], []); // 2. start with an empty array
  
const input ={
  a: 'apple',
  b:{
    c:{
      d:{
        e: 'egg',
        f: 'fish'
      }
    },
    g: 'guava',
    h: 'honey',
  }
}

console.log(getDeepValues(input))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but i need to understand if there is a possibility to use pure ramda in this scenario

Comment: @B_B: Unless this is a learning exercise, I'd be careful with the notion of using "pure ramda".  Ramda is a library, not a framework.  It's meant to make a certain style of coding easier, but not to dictate how you write your own code.  Use it when -- and only when! -- it makes your code simpler.  The answer from Ori Drori shows both Ramda and vanilla JS versions.  The vanilla one to my mind is simpler; it's what I would choose.  (And I'm one of the founders of Ramda.)